# Firebase query run on local emulators does not work on live?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

**This query does not run on live site but run on local emulators
I need help for this problem**

```
let data = await firebase.firestore().collection('logs')
      .where('date','>=',dateRange.first)
      .where('date','<=',dateRange.second)
      .where('doctorCode','==',parseInt(searchDoctorCode))
      // .orderBy('date', 'desc')
      .get(); 
      if(data.docs.length === 0){
        console.log('There are No Data ' );
        setData([]);
      }else{
        setData(data.docs.map((sn)=>{
          console.log(sn.data());
          sum = sum + parseFloat(sn.data().totalRecieved);
          return sn.data();
          }
          )
        )
      }
      setSumTable(sum);
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what "does not run" and "run" mean here? What line of the code you shared doesn't do what you expect it to do on the actual database?

Comment: First thanks very much , run mean that query retrieve data from database in local emulators but online does not retrieve any data and no errors

Comment: Can you edit your question to show a document that you expect to be returned from the real database, and that isn't being returned?

Comment: The question is "What is the documents whose doctorCode field between the two dates first and second in date field

Comment: The problem is solved by creating composite index with the two fields doctorCode and date , but I want to know if this the best practice or there is another solution ?